# generate json data with mysql help

Tags: json

Any idea how to get this out put with queries?

```
$obj = array(
    "attr" => array(
      "id" => 1,
      "rel" => "drive"                  
      ),
    "data" => "My Documents",

    "children" => array(
      array(
    "attr" => array(
      "id" => 2,
      "rel" => "file"
      ),
    "data" => "file1.doc",
    "state" => ""
    )
      ) 
    );

echo json_encode($obj);
```

i need to loop only below part of above code.

```
array(
    "attr" => array(
      "id" => 2,
      "rel" => "file"
      ),
    "data" => "file1.doc",
    "state" => ""
    )
```

any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Need way more information, like table structure, code you've already tried, etc.

Comment: this is the query "SELECT id,rel,data FROM tbl_files WHERE parent_id = '$id' ORDER BY id" i want loop the array with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$x = 0;
while($row = mssql_fetch_object($query) )
{
   $json[$x] = array    (   
                            'lastname' => $row->firstname,
                            'firstname' => $row->lastname
                        );  
   $x++;
}
echo  json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Thanks vick, but is there way to loop a array that in inside a array?

Answer (score 0):

You might try compiling and installing the third-party JSON UDFs:

http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_json/index.php

Comment: is it possible on shared hosting?